# DNS reverse resolution

Tags: dns

I'm learning DNS and I have a question about reverse resolution.

On *[Wikipedia french version](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System?oldformat=true#R.C3.A9solution_inverse)* it's said that if *client A* has `192.168.0.0/25` and *client B* has `192.168.0.128/25` then to resolve an IP from client A it would go through this path (from right to left):

`0.168.192.in-addr.arp` and this would cause a problem for *client B* who can't do the same.

I don't understand this last affirmation, **what prevents client B to do the same ?**

Answer (score 1):

Here `192.168.0.0/25` is not a **IP address**, its a **Network ID**.

`Client A IP: 192.168.0.1/25
Reverse lookup: 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arp`

`Client B IP: 192.168.0.128/25
Reverse lookup: 128.0.168.192.in-addr.arp`

Without any issues **PTR** lookup should work. Not sure why it says?

Comment: It says that "it's not possible to give client A 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa for him to define the PTRs (corresponding to its hosts), because it would prencent client B to do the same".

Comment: 192.168.0.0 is not a IP address and hence it cannot.